# Way to find: $a^n \equiv -1 \mod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Fermat's Little Theorem states that if $a$ is an integer and $p$ a prime:

$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$$

This is particularly helpful while calculating congruences.

Is there such a theorem/way to find $n$ such that:

$$a^n \equiv -1 \mod p$$

Comment: See [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Comment: Does $n$ depend on $a$?

Comment: What Bill said. A summary of elementary facts: If $a$ is a quadratic non-residue, then $n=(p-1)/2$ works, but it is a bit more difficult to say if a smaller $n$ works. Any proper divisor of $(p-1)/2$ is the smallest working exponent for some $a$. If $a$ is a quadratic residue, and $p\equiv3\pmod4$, then no $n$ works.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^n+1\equiv 0 \ mod p$

If n is odd we can write:

$a^n+1=(a+1)(a^{n-1}-a^{a-2}+a^{a-3}- 
\cdot\cdot\cdot +1)$

p can be a primes factor of RHS of above relation, for example:

$2^5+1=33=3\times 11$

p can be 3 or 11 such that :

$2^5=32\equiv -1 \mod33\equiv -1 \mod 3\equiv -1 \mod 11$

Also due to Euler's criterion if $n=\frac {p-1}2$ and a is co-prime with p we have:

$a^{\frac {p-1}2}=-1 \mod p$

For example p=7 , then:

$n=\frac{7-1}2=3$

Now take a=13 we have:

$13^3=2197=313\times 7+6\equiv 6 \ mod 7\equiv -1 \ mod 7$

a must not have this relation with p:

$a \equiv k^2\mod p $

for example

$11=4+7$ and $4=2^2$

But $13=6+7$ and 6 is not perfect square.

Comment: Then, why do people use Fermat's theorem at all instead of Euler's criterion?

Comment: @Shub, People also use Euler's criterion whenever it is necessary, like in this answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for a way:

Let $m_0 \ge 1$ be the smallest integer satisfying $a^{m_0} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Then

There exist $n \ge 1$ such that $a^n \equiv -1 \pmod p$ if and only if $m_0$ is even. Moreover, when $m_0$ is even, the smallest $n$ is found with

$$n = \frac{m_0}{2}$$